# NameError: name 'classname' is not defined error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I was working on a python program. I have created a class named "Perception". The code is given below:

```js
import numpy as np
class Perceptron(object):

    def __init__(self, eta=0.01, n_iter=10):
        self.eta=eta
        self.n_iter=n_iter


    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.w_=np.zeros(1+X.shape[1])
        self.errors_ = []

        for _ in range(self.n_iter):
            errors =0
            for xi,target in zip(X,y):
                update = self.eta * (target - self.predict(xi))
                self.w_[1:] += update * xi
                self.w_[0] += update
                errors += int(update != 0.0)
            self.errors_.append(errors)
        return self

    def net_input(self, X):
        """Calculate net input"""
        return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]

    def predict(self, X):
        """Return class label after unit step"""
        return np.where(self.net_input(X) >= 0.0, 1, -1)
```

when i want to declare the class in the following line:

```
ppn = Perceptron(eta=0.1, n_iter=10)
```

I get the following error:

**NameError: name 'Perceptron' is not defined**

I am new to Python. Please help me in the next steps. And Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your use of the class (i.e. `ppn = Perceptron(eta=0.1, n_iter=10)`) in a different file?

Comment: Adding to the above, you may need to import `Perceptron` first.

Answer (score 2):

```
Run this it should work , if not share the screen hot of code and output.
import numpy as np
class Perceptron(object):

    def __init__(self, eta=0.01, n_iter=10):
        self.eta=eta
        self.n_iter=n_iter


    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.w_=np.zeros(1+X.shape[1])
        self.errors_ = []

        for _ in range(self.n_iter):
            errors =0
            for xi,target in zip(X,y):
                update = self.eta * (target - self.predict(xi))
                self.w_[1:] += update * xi
                self.w_[0] += update
                errors += int(update != 0.0)
            self.errors_.append(errors)
        return self

    def net_input(self, X):
        """Calculate net input"""
        return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]

    def predict(self, X):
        """Return class label after unit step"""
        return np.where(self.net_input(X) >= 0.0, 1, -1)



ppn = Perceptron(eta=0.1, n_iter=10)
```

Comment: What have you changed more exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You should call ppn = Perceptron.Perceptron(eta=0.1, n_iter=10)